# How to connect to a VPN?

Tags: vpn, kubuntu, vpnc

I am a newbie on this subject, and I was told to connect to a VPN from my computer, which is running Kubuntu 13.10. I was also given the server to connect to (vpn.server_x.com:81), a user and its password. The last data I have is that this is a openconnect on Linux.

I read several tutorials and I tried with vpnc, openvpn and pptp-linux, because I do not know which I have to use. I always get errors, and reading /var/log/syslog is not being very useful because I do not know if I am doing stupid things.

For example, at the beginning I supposed that I had to use vpnc, so I installed it and then created a new connection via the Network settings, but it asks me for Gateway, User name, User password, Group name and Group password. In gateway I wrote vpn.server_x.com:81, but I do not have enough data to fill in the rest.

Am I creating the right VPN connection?

Comment: It should be as simple as using the vpn client supported by the vpn server itself and using your credentials to log into the acccount.

Comment: @Ramhound Thank you! So, if they are using a Cisco VPN Server for example, I should install a Cisco VPN Client on my computer, am I right? And the Cisco VPN Client is vpnc, isn't it?

Comment: I would ask your IT Department what client they want you to be using.  Even if you use the proper client you don't have all the information to log into your account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed the solution, I did not have to install neither vpnc nor openvpn nor pptp.

I had to install openconnect. Then, the process is similar to others, add the VPN in the connection editor but selecting openconnect instead of the other ones. If I do this, I am only asked for gateway, username and password, so the data I was given is enough.